# Consecutive observations by Month and Year

Tags: r, lubridate

Thank you guys for your help thus far! Just want to get some help on one last question. This is my data...

```
Year Month Day Hour   DateTime
1950  1     4   12    1/4/1950 12:00
1950  1     4   13    1/4/1950 13:00 
1950  1     4   14    1/4/1950 14:00 
1950  1     4   15    1/4/1950 15:00 
1950  1     4   18    1/4/1950 18:00 
1950  1     4   21    1/4/1950 21:00 
1950  1     4   22    1/4/1950 22:00 
1950  1     5   23    1/5/1950 23:00
```

*I spaced the data out so you could see which data goes with which column*

I used this code below..

rle(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dt, unit = "hour") != 1)))$lengths

to create a list of values that denotes the number of consecutive observations. So, for example, the first value is 4 (because the first four observations are consecutive) then 1, then 3. This is exactly what I want, but I would like to have these values by month and year. For example, I'd like my result to look as follows...

```
Year Month Consecutive 
1950   1      4 
1950   1      1 
1950   1      3
```

Where the consecutive column corresponds to the number of consecutive values from the above data but its also by year and month. I'm not concerned with cutting events off at the end of months or years. Currently, I do not know where the months and years are, just the simple list of consecutive sums!!! Also, thank you for whoever supplied the first code!

Comment: Based on the example provided, the expected output doesn't seems to be grouped by 'Year' or 'Month'

Comment: I'm just trying to get a those consecutive counts grouped in their respective month or year, I don't care if its in a new vector or a new column in the dataset.

Comment: okay, then try the solution posted below

Comment: When I run that code I only get back the Consecutive column, there is no year or month.

Comment: For me, it is not the case.  I updated with the example used

Comment: Does you result have more than one column? I'm getting a 3024 by 1 vector with the only column being consecutive

Comment: I get 3 columns exactly but the output is `4 1 2 1` as the last day is `1/5` instead of `1/4`

Comment: I had a punctuation mistake in there! Always something! But thank you I got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do with a group by operation (assuming the 'DateTime' is converted to `datetime` class)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
   group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
   summarise(Consecutive = list(rle(cumsum(c(TRUE, 
         diff(DateTime, unit = "hour") != 1)))$lengths)) %>%
   unnest
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1950L, 1950L, 1950L, 1950L, 1950L, 1950L, 
1950L, 1950L), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Day = c(4L, 
 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), Hour = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 
 21L, 22L, 23L), DateTime = c("1/4/1950 12:00", "1/4/1950 13:00", 
 "1/4/1950 14:00", "1/4/1950 15:00", "1/4/1950 18:00", "1/4/1950 21:00", 
 "1/4/1950 22:00", "1/5/1950 23:00")), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```